# Scrolling Titles are cut off in vertical video

Tags: final-cut-pro-x

I'm editing a video in vertical/portrait orientation and I'm trying to have scrolling credits. The credits don't scroll in at the bottom of the video and the don't scroll out at the top. It looks like they're bounded by a horizontal/landscape box.

What do I need to change to have them scroll from the bottom of the video to the top of the video?

[image: The bottom is cut off on these scrolling credits.]

[image: The top is cut off on these scrolling credits.]

Answer (score 1):

Double tapping on the bounding box revealed anchors that I used to stretch to the top and bottom.

[image: Scrolling text generator with handles to stretch it.]